# Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, postgresql-9.1, generate-series

I have a query like this that nicely generates a series of dates between 2 given dates:

```
select date '2004-03-07' + j - i as AllDate 
from generate_series(0, extract(doy from date '2004-03-07')::int - 1) as i,
     generate_series(0, extract(doy from date '2004-08-16')::int - 1) as j
```

It generates 162 dates between `2004-03-07` and `2004-08-16` and this what I want. The problem with this code is that it wouldn't give the right answer when the two dates are from different years, for example when I try `2007-02-01` and `2008-04-01`.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting date list in a range in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391085/getting-date-list-in-a-range-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

Can be done without conversion to/from int (but to/from timestamp instead)

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
FROM generate_series
        ( '2007-02-01'::timestamp 
        , '2008-04-01'::timestamp
        , '1 day'::interval) dd
        ;
```

Comment: why is `date_trunc` needed?

Comment: It's just presentation. It eliminates the printing of the time part of the timestamp which is alwas zeros in this case.

Comment: `date_trunc` is not needed because you're already coercing it to a `date` type with `::date`. It produces the same result with or without it.

Comment: IIRC date_trunc() was needed in older versions (8.4 ?). Anyway, it won't harm, and you could always try to omit the casts.

Answer (score 133):

To generate a series of ***dates*** this is the ***optimal*** way:

```
SELECT t.day::date 
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2004-03-07'
                     , timestamp '2004-08-16'
                     , interval  '1 day') AS t(day);
```

- Additional `date_trunc()` is not needed. The cast to `date` (`day::date`) does that implicitly.
- But there is also no point in casting date literals to `date` as input parameter. Au contraire, **`timestamp` is the best choice**. The advantage in performance is small, but there is no reason not to take it. And you do not needlessly involve DST (daylight saving time) rules coupled with the conversion from `date` to `timestamp with time zone` and back. See below.

Equivalent, less explicit short syntax:

```
SELECT day::date 
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2004-03-07', '2004-08-16', '1 day') day;
```

Or with the set-returning function in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2004-03-07', '2004-08-16', '1 day')::date AS day;
```

The `AS` keyword is *required* in the last variant, Postgres would misinterpret the column alias `day` otherwise. And I would *not* advise that variant before Postgres 10 - at least not with more than one set-returning function in the same `SELECT` list:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

(That aside, the last variant is typically fastest by a tiny margin.)

#### Why `timestamp [without time zone]`?

There are a number of overloaded variants of [**`generate_series()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES). Currently (Postgres 11):

> ```
> SELECT oid::regprocedure   AS function_signature
>      , prorettype::regtype AS return_type
> FROM   pg_proc
> where  proname = 'generate_series';
> ```
>
> ```
> function_signature                                                                | return_type                
> :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :--------------------------
> generate_series(integer,integer,integer)                                          | integer                    
> generate_series(integer,integer)                                                  | integer                    
> generate_series(bigint,bigint,bigint)                                             | bigint                     
> generate_series(bigint,bigint)                                                    | bigint                     
> generate_series(numeric,numeric,numeric)                                          | numeric                    
> generate_series(numeric,numeric)                                                  | numeric                    
> generate_series(timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone,interval) | timestamp without time zone
> generate_series(timestamp with time zone,timestamp with time zone,interval)       | timestamp with time zone
> ```

(`numeric` variants were added with Postgres 9.5.) The relevant ones are the last two **in bold** taking and returning `timestamp` / `timestamptz`.

There is **no variant taking or returning `date`**. An explicit cast is needed to return `date`. The call with `timestamp` arguments resolves to the best variant directly without descending into function type resolution rules and without additional cast for the input.

`timestamp '2004-03-07'` is perfectly valid, btw. The omitted time part defaults to `00:00` with ISO format.

Thanks to [**function type resolution**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) we can still pass `date`. But that requires more work from Postgres. There is an ***implicit* cast** from `date` to `timestamp` as well as one from `date` to `timestamptz`. Would be ambiguous, but `timestamptz` is **"preferred"** among "date/time types". So the [match is decided at step *4d.*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html):

> Run through all candidates and keep those that accept preferred types
>   (of the input data type's type category) at the most positions where
>   type conversion will be required. Keep all candidates if none accept
>   preferred types. If only one candidate remains, use it; else continue
>   to the next step.

In addition to the extra work in function type resolution this adds an extra cast to `timestamptz` - which not only adds more cost, it can also introduce problems with DST leading to unexpected results in rare cases. (DST is a moronic concept, btw, can't stress this enough.) Related:

- [How do I generate a date series in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175963/3684)
- [How do I generate a time series in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158907/3684)

I added demos to the fiddle showing the more expensive query plan:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2750de77507cb4bd3ed2b7cf972e4bc6)*

Related:

- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)
- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)
- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)

Comment: Even more shorter version: `SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2004-03-07', '2004-08-16', '1 day') :: DATE AS day;`

Comment: What does the t(day) syntax signify?

Comment: @rendang: `AS t(day)` in `SELECT * FROM func() AS t(day)` are table and column alias. The `AS` keyword is optional noise in this context. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20230716/939860

Comment: Are you sure about this? "timestamp '2004-03-07' is perfectly valid, btw. The omitted time part defaults to 00:00 with ISO format." <- it sounds like it would depend on postgres.conf or session timezone, no?

Comment: @Seivan: Absolutely sure. ISO 8601 format is unambiguous, regardless of locale or datestyle setting. (Recommended for all date / time literals.) See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE

Comment: I just missed the `[without...` part, my bad. Just to be clear, if you omit offset, Z or abrev/name it will actually convert it based on your session, but that's with timestamptz, not timestamp. My bad.

Comment: betwen years!

SELECT t.day::date
from generate_series (
 ((current_timestamp - interval '70 year')),
 ((current_timestamp - interval '18 year')),
 interval '1 day'
) as t(day) order by random() limit 1

Answer (score 41):

You can generate series directly with dates. No need to use ints or timestamps:

```
select date::date 
from generate_series(
  '2004-03-07'::date,
  '2004-08-16'::date,
  '1 day'::interval
) date;
```

Comment: Depending on your time zone, this may return an unexpected result. I had this problem.

Use the timestamp instead.


    SET session TIME zone 'America/Sao_Paulo'  

    SELECT d::date FROM generate_series('2019-11-01'::date, '2019-11-03'::date, '1 day') d

    SELECT d::date FROM generate_series('2019-11-01'::date, '2019-11-04'::date, '1 day') d

Comment: What is the problem with this code? I ran it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0d7b2b8d07ddc037a151efe806ad1b01) (back to version 9.6) and it runs fine!

Comment: @Vérace see [Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/192740)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this.

```
select generate_series  ( '2012-12-31'::timestamp , '2018-10-31'::timestamp , '1 day'::interval) :: date
```