# Combine 2 tables to join to

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, cross-join, generate-series

I'm using Postgres 9.1 and I have a query which returns 2 columns which I would like replicated even if no data is present.  The important parts of my query are

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id FROM (...)
WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) GROUP BY interval_time, institution_id
```

This returns to me all institutions and all interval_times just like I'd expect.  Now I also want rows where there is no data.  I can do the following to get either one at a time

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id FROM (...)
WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) GROUP BY interval_time, institution_id
RIGHT JOIN generate_series('2012-02-03', '2013-02-18', interval '1 week')
ON DATE_TRUNC('week', generate_series) = interval_time
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id FROM (...)
WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) GROUP BY interval_time, institution_id
RIGHT JOIN unnest(array[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]) AS all_institution_id
ON all_institution_id = institution_id
```

however, I'd like to combine them, so that I get all interval_times for all institutions.  It seems like the best thing to do is to create some kind of intermediate table which contains each institution_id repeated for each interval_time and then RIGHT JOIN on that, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

After playing around a little bit, it seems like what I want do to is the following, but my syntax is wrong

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id FROM (...)
WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) GROUP BY interval_time, institution_id
RIGHT JOIN unnest(array[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]) AS all_institution_id,
generate_series('2012-02-03', '2013-02-18', interval '1 week')
ON DATE_TRUNC('week', generate_series) = dose_hsts.interval_time
AND all_institution_id = institution_id
```

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `CROSS JOIN` before you do the `LEFT JOIN` (replacing the `RIGHT JOIN` to the same effect here):

```
SELECT interval_time::date , institution_id, ...
FROM   generate_series(date_trunc('week', timestamp '2012-02-03')
                     , timestamp '2013-02-18'
                     , interval '1 week')   AS d(interval_time)
CROSS  JOIN unnest(array[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]) AS i(institution_id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id
   FROM   ...
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) x USING (interval_time, institution_id);
```

About `generate_series()`:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is UNION both queries.
Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id FROM (...)
WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) GROUP BY interval_time, institution_id
UNION
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id FROM (...)
WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) GROUP BY interval_time, institution_id
RIGHT JOIN generate_series('2012-02-03', '2013-02-18', interval '1 week')
ON DATE_TRUNC('week', generate_series) = interval_time
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using the following syntax

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', tx_dttm) AS interval_time, institution_id FROM (...)
WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) GROUP BY interval_time, institution_id
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM unnest(array[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]) AS all_institution_id,
generate_series('2012-02-03', '2013-02-18', interval '1 week'))
ON DATE_TRUNC('week', generate_series) = dose_hsts.interval_time
AND all_institution_id = institution_id
```