# Why is a random String/varchar after the table name valid?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Why is the following query a valid select ?

```
SELECT * from arelation somerandomtext;
```

The content of `arelation` does not matter, it just hast to be an existing view/table.

It returns the correct result, respectively the output of the select without the `somerandomtext`.

Why does this query do not throw an error/exception, is there no keyword (Group By, limit...) check ?

Comment: This is called a table alias and is a fundamental part of the SQL language -- required for instance to do self-joins.  They are described in the Postgres documentation here (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

Comment: I always use(d)  the the alias function with "as" , so this point did not came to my mind.

Comment: I always use `as` for column aliases and never for table aliases -- probably the influence of Oracle earlier in my life (Oracle does not allow `as` for table aliases).

Comment: Yup!! Oracle supports 'AS' for aliasing columns only..

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Always using `AS` for *column aliases* (while the same is optional for table aliases) is also recommended for Postgres. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229979/query-to-order-by-the-number-of-rows-returned-from-another-select/20230716#20230716).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an alias

i.e.

```
select c.id, c.* 
from products c
```

is valid syntax as it allows joins from a table to itself

i.e.

```
select c.id, p.id 
from products c inner join products p on p.id = c.id
```