# SELECTing for the other user of the pair

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following structure (simplified for brevity). I am mostly frontend developer that suddenly needs to learn the basics of SQL, so bear with me, please :)

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    id text NOT NULL,
    lastOnlineAt timestamptz NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE pair (
    id text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE userPair (
    userId text NOT NULL,
    pairId text NOT NULL
);
```

The important aspect here is that every `pair` is linked to exactly 2 `user` entities (through `userPair`). I am not sure if was the wisest approach, but I did not like the idea of having columns `user1/2` inside the `pair`.

Now I need to do a SELECT that for every `user` finds associated `pair`s, picks the other `user` of that `pair` and gets his `lastOnlineAt` for a comparison. Effectively I need to find paired users that were online in the last 5 minutes.

I would probably start like this.

```sql
SELECT up.'pairId' 
  FROM 'userPair' AS up 
       LEFT JOIN pair as p 
 WHERE up.'userId' = $userId 
   AND p.id = up.'pairId'
```

But then I am getting lost in complexity here.

It's for the Postgres 12.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images.) [mcve].

Comment: I am not sure what data do you expect to see there, just a bunch of text-based IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax errors in that a `left join` needs an `on` and identifiers cannot be enclosed in single quotes since that makes them literals.

You need to join `userpair` twice to get what you want:

```
SELECT u2.* 
  FROM "userPair" AS p1 
       JOIN "userPair" p2 
         ON p2."pairId" =  p1."pairId"
        AND p2."userId" != p1."userId"
       JOIN "user" u2 
         ON u2.id = p2."userId" 
 WHERE p1."userId" = $userId 
   AND u2."lastOnlineAt" >= now() - interval '5 minutes'
```

Also, using camel case for identifier is very bad idea.

Comment: Yea, I am constantly lost about which quotes do what. As I said, I am mostly frontend dev, so I am learning on the road. I did not know that SQL can't handle camelCase and since I am used it from the code, I thought it's fine. Too late for that now :)

Comment: @FredyC  It's not that it cannot handle it, it is that the default without using double quotes will lowercase the identifier.  So if you have camelcase, you have to enclose them in double quotes to prevent that lowercasing.  That leads to headaches.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. So simple and elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a lateral join:

```
select u.*
from userpair p cross join lateral
     (values (userid, pairid), (pairid, userid)
     ) v(theuserid, theotherid) join
     users u 
     on u.id = v.theotherid
where v.theuserid = ?;
```

This uses the lateral join to split the data into two pairs -- with the users in either order.  The first is matched to the input.  The second is the other one that is returned.

Comment: Well, you got me, I have no idea what's going on here :) What is "v" and what's the `v(theuserid, theotherid)` supposed to me?

Comment: @FredyC . . . `v` is a table alias.  The others are the names of the columns in the `values`.

Comment: Wait, but where are you declaring that `v` alias? I see only `u` and `p` defined. The `v` is just used out of nowhere.

Comment: The alias `v` is for `(values (userid, pairid), (pairid, userid))`.

Comment: Ah, that really confused me. You don't need to use "AS"?

Comment: @FredyC: The keyword `AS` is optional.  But don't omit it for column aliases. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20230716/939860