# Generate series of dates - using date type as input

Tags: postgresql, types, timestamp, postgresql-9.1, generate-series

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) for `generate_series` says that argument can be `int` or `bigint` for `generate_series(start, stop)` and `generate_series(start, stop, step)` cases and `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone` for `generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`.

What is the reason that `generate_series` works also with `date` type as input and returns `timestamp with timezone`?

```
pg=# select generate_series('2014-01-01'::date,'2014-01-02'::date,'1 day');
    generate_series     
------------------------
 2014-01-01 00:00:00+01
 2014-01-02 00:00:00+01
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Note that my original explanation had errors. It's been a couple of years, but you may still be interested in the update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [**function type resolution**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) we can also pass `date` values to  [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) because there is an *implicit* cast from `date` to `timestamp` as well as from `date` to `timestamptz`. Would be ambiguous, but `timestamptz` is **"preferred"** among "Date/time types". Detailed explanation:

- **[Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)**

For a bare `date` the local time `00:00` is assumed in the cast. Be aware that the current time zone setting directly affects the result if you use `date` as input since, obviously, '2014-01-10 00:00' represents a different point in time in Tokio than it does in New York.

#### How does Postgres decide what types are acceptable?

Postgres basically distinguishes between [three types of casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html):

`Explicit casts` ..  when using `CAST` or `::` syntax.
`Assignment cast` .. implicit cast when a value is assigned to a target column.
`Implicit cast` .. implicit casts in all other expressions.

There has to be an *implicit* cast registered in the system from the input type to the expected type to make a function silently accept (and convert) an input value.

To see which casts are defined *to* `timestamptz`, you can query the catalog table [`pg_cast`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html):

```
SELECT castsource::regtype, casttarget::regtype, castcontext
FROM   pg_cast
WHERE  casttarget = 'timestamptz'::regtype;

         castsource          |        casttarget        | castcontext
-----------------------------+--------------------------+-------------
 abstime                     | timestamp with time zone | i
 date                        | timestamp with time zone | i
 timestamp without time zone | timestamp with time zone | i
 timestamp with time zone    | timestamp with time zone | i
```

All of these casts are *implicit*. The manual on [`castcontext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html):

> Indicates what contexts the cast can be invoked in. `e` means only as an
> explicit cast (using `CAST` or `::` syntax). `a` means implicitly in
> assignment to a target column, as well as explicitly. **`i` means
> implicitly in expressions, as well as the other cases.**

Bold emphasis mine.