# Return setof record with 1 row

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm altering a `PLPGSQL` function and I'm having a small problem. First let me post it's declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION permissions(_principal text)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    id integer := 0;
    rolerow record ;
```

In this function there are a few cases, controled by `IF` statements, and in all of them, the return is the `UNION` of more than 1 query, such as this:

```
FOR rolerow IN (
    (SELECT 'role1' AS role FROM table1 WHERE id = table1.id)
    UNION (SELECT 'role2' AS role FROM table2 WHERE id = table2.id)
    UNION (SELECT 'role3' AS role FROM table3 WHERE id = table3.id)
    ) 
LOOP
    RETURN NEXT rolerow;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
```

And it all works fine, but in one case, I need to return a single query result, that would be a `SETOF record` but with only 1 item, so I did it like this:

```
FOR rolerow IN (
    SELECT 'role4' AS role FROM table4 WHERE id = table4.id
) 
LOOP
    RETURN NEXT rolerow;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
```

I also tried

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT 'role4' AS role FROM table4 WHERE id = table4.id;
```

But in both cases I get the same error as a response:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type unknown does not match expected type text in column 1.
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

I'll provide extra information in case this isn't enough.

Comment: Consider using `RETURNS SETOF TEXT` (if your structure is really that simple) as it does not require you to always alias your result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an explicit cast for the string literal `'role4'`, which is *not* typed (type "unknown") unlike you seem to expect:

```
 SELECT 'role4'::text AS role FROM  ...
```

Generally, looping is more expensive for your simple examples. Use [**`RETURN QUERY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) like you already tested.

Comment: If you had posted a *complete* function I would answer with a complete function.

Comment: It worked :) I knew it was something really simple, but I couldn't get a handle on it. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Just a quick question, do you know why I need to explicitly say that it's `text` even though I'm writing a literal text? If you have a link or something it'd be great

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki: That's a common misconception. A string literal like `'foo'` is just that: a string literal (of type `unknown`) in Postgres until it is *cast* to a data type. For the human eye, it's "text" already, but from PostgreSQL's perspective, not so much. `text` is a data type just like any other - the same word, a related, but different thing. It just so happens to be the default type for string literals in certain situations, where it is cast automatically. But not here.

Comment: I understand, I'll study this deeper so that I don't fall to these rookie mistakes again. I thank you very much for your help on this, and the explanation!

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki: When assigning a string literal (or a close relative of the target type) to a column or variable (plpgsql) of a well-known type, the value is cast automatically as long as at least an assignment cast is registered in the system. There are basically three types  ... [details in this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215).