# GIN index on smallint[] column not used or error "operator is not unique"

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, operator-overloading, postgresql-9.5

```
create table test(
    id serial primary key,
    tagged smallint[]
);
```

There is gin index on `tagged` column, with `_int2_ops` operator class:

`CREATE INDEX ix ON test USING GIN(col _int2_ops);`

When I run this query:

```
select * from test
where tagged @> ARRAY[11]
order by id limit 100;
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..19524.39 rows=100 width=36) (actual time=25024.124..25027.263 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.43..508404.37 rows=2604 width=36) (actual time=25024.121..25027.251 rows=100 loops=1)
        Filter: ((tagged)::integer[] @> '{11}'::integer[])
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2399999
Planning time: 6.912 ms
Execution time: 25027.307 ms
```

Bold emphasis mine. Why is the `tagged` column converted to `integer[]` type? I think this is the reason why GIN the index isn't used and the query runs slow.

I tried `WHERE  tagged @> ARRAY[11]::smallint[]` but got this error:

> ```
> operator is not unique: smallint[] @> smallint[]
> ```

If I do the same but use `tagged int[]` and create index as

```
CREATE INDEX ix ON test USING GIN(tagged gin__int_ops);
```

then the above query uses the GIN index:

> ```
> "->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix  (cost=0.00..1575.53 rows=2604 width=0) (actual time=382.840..382.840 rows=2604480 loops=1)"
> "   Index Cond: (tagged @> '{11}'::integer[])"
> ```

This is a bit faster than previous, but It takes on average 10 second - still too slow. I want to try `smallint[]` instead of `int[]`, maybe that will be faster ...

Comment: Beacuse of `order by id limit 100` the planner thinks that using the primary key will be faster than the gin index. The cast to int[] does not matter.

Comment: @klin please see update

Comment: Really interesting, there is something to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solution

Most probably, the **solution** is to schema-qualify the operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  tagged OPERATOR(pg_catalog.@>) '{11}'::int2[]
ORDER  BY id
LIMIT  100;
```

#### Why?

It's a problem of **operator resolution** (in combination with type resolution and cast context).

In standard Postgres, there is only a single candidate operator `anyarray @> anyarray`, that's the one you want.

Your setup would work just fine if you had not installed the **additional module [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html)** (my assumption), which provides another operator for `integer[] @> integer[]`.

*Hence, another solution would be to use `integer[]` instead and have a GIN index with the [`gin__int_ops` operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.29.8). Or try the (default for intarray) `gist__int_ops` index. Either might be faster, but both don't allow NULL values.

Or you could rename the `intarray` operator `@>` to disambiguate. (I would not do that. Upgrade and portability issues ensue.)*

For expressions involving at least one operand of type `integer[]`, Postgres knows which operator to pick: the intarray operator. But then the ***index is not applicable***, because the intarray operator only operates on `integer` (`int4`) not `int2`. And indexes are strictly bound to operators:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)
- [PostgreSQL behavior in presence of two different type of indexes on the same column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/150585/3684)

But for `int2[] @> int2[]`, Postgres is unable to decide the best operator. Both seem equally applicable. Since the default operator is provided in the `pg_catalog` schema and the intarray operator is provided in the `public` schema (by default - or wherever you installed the extension), you can help solve the conundrum by schema-qualifying the operator with the [`OPERATOR()` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-OPERATOR-CALLS). Related:

- [Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements/12870508#12870508)

The error message you get is a bit misleading. But if you look closely, there is a `HINT` line added which hints (tada!) in the right direction:

```
ERROR:  operator is not unique: smallint[] @> smallint[]
LINE 1: SELECT NULL::int2[] @> NULL::int2[]
                            ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

You can investigate existing operator candidates for `@>` with:

```
SELECT o.oid, *, oprleft::regtype, oprright::regtype, n.nspname
FROM   pg_operator o
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = o.oprnamespace
WHERE  oprname = '@>';
```

Another alternative solution would be to temporarily(!) set a different search_path, so only the desired operator is found. In the same transaction:

```
SET LOCAL search_path = pg_catalog;
SELECT ...
```

But then you have to schema-qualify all tables in the query.

About cast context:

- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)

You *could* change the `castcontext` of `int2` -> `int4`. But I strongly advise against it. Too many possible side effects:

- [Is there any way to cast postgresql 9.3 data type so that it can affect only one side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624042/is-there-any-way-to-cast-postgresql-9-3-data-type-so-that-it-can-affect-only-one/24624911#24624911)

Comment: Complete and helpful answer, as always