# Query with filter on value in a jsonb array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, search, jsonb

I have a column with type `jsonb` holding a list of IDs as plain JSON array in my PostgreSQL 9.6.6 database and I want to search this field based on any ID in the list. How to query write this query?

```
'[1,8,3,4,56,6]'
```

For example, my table is:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    numbers jsonb
);
```

And it has some values:

```
 id  |  numbers
-----+-------
 1   | "[1,8,3,4,56,6]"
 2   | "[1,2,7,4,24,5]"
```

I want something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE
id = 1
AND
numbers::json->>VALUE(56)
;
```

Expected result (only if the JSON array has `56` as element):

```
 id  |  numbers
-----+-------
 1   | "[1,8,3,4,56,6]"
```

---

**Step-2 problem :**

The result of this command is `TRUE` :

```
SELECT '[1,8,3,4,56,6]'::jsonb @> '56';
```

but already when I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
numbers::jsonb @> '[56]';
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
numbers::jsonb @> '56';
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
numbers::jsonb @> '[56]'::jsonb;
```

The result is nothing :

```
 id  |  numbers
-----+-------
(0 rows)
```

Instead of be this :

```
 id  |  numbers
-----+-------
 1   | "[1,8,3,4,56,6]"
```

---

**I find why I get `(0 rows)` ! :))**

because I insert jsonb value to mytable with double quotation , in fact this is correct value format (without double quotation ):

```
 id  |  numbers
-----+-------
 1   | [1,8,3,4,56,6]
 2   | [1,2,7,4,24,5]
```

now when run this command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
numbers @> '56';
```

The result is :

```
 id  |  numbers
-----+-------
 1   | [1,8,3,4,56,6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `jsonb` "contains" operator `@>`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
WHERE  id = 1
AND    numbers @> '[56]';
```

Or

```
...
AND    numbers @> '56';
```

Works with our without enclosing array brackets in this case.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8d5fe6ef374aadccd7ed2972d54d2f7d)*

This can be supported with various kinds of indexes for great read performance if your table is big.

Detailed explanation / instructions:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706#)

---

Hint (addressing [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137311/posgres-where-exist-value-in-jsonb-list/48137527#comment83252466_48137527)): when testing with string literals, be sure to add an explicit cast:

```
SELECT '[1,8,3,4,56,6]'::jsonb @> '56';
```

If you don't, Postgres does not know which data types to assume. There are multiple options:

```
SELECT '[1,8,3,4,56,6]' @> '56';
```

> ```
> ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown @> unknown
> ```

Related:

- [GIN index on smallint[] column not used or error "operator is not unique"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798993/gin-index-on-smallint-column-not-used-or-error-operator-is-not-unique/39802812#39802812)

Comment: I get this error : 
ERROR : operator is not unique: unknown @> unknown
HINT: Could not choose a best candidate operator ...

Comment: @MojtabaArvin: Doesn't make sense. I tested in Postgres 9.6, it's working. What's your version of Postgres? (Should be in the question to begin with.)

Comment: You would't get `unknown` in the error msg if the column is type `jsonb`. You probably tested with untyped string literals, which is misleading.

Comment: How do I search for multiple values like 

AND    numbers @> '[56,4]';

How do I search for any values from 

AND    numbers @> '[56]' OR '[4]';

Comment: @ajitpawarink: One way: `numbers @> ANY ('{56, 4}'::jsonb[])`, which is short for `(numbers @> '56'::jsonb OR numbers @> '7'::jsonb);` Or `numbers @? '$[*] ? (@ == 56 || @ == 7)'`. Unfortunately, `numbers ?| '{56, 7}'::text[]` only works for *string* elements, not for *numeric* elements. Start a separate question if you need more details.