# What difference between NULL and NULL::character varying in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, casting, default-value

Is there a difference between default values of column in PostgreSQL? Whether this is important?

```
state character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

and

```
state character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no effective difference in the presented example in a standard installation.

Without explicit cast, `NULL` of data type `unknown` will be coerced to `varchar` in an [assignment cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) automatically. See:

- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)

In other situations, where the type cannot be derived from context, you may need to cast explicitly - to tell Postgres the intended type of the value. This is rarely the case, though.