# PostgreSQL increase column length

Tags: postgresql, types, dynamic-sql, ddl

Example I have table named from `A` - `Z` , but only

```
    table "A" and table "J"
```

have a

```
    column clm varchar(10).
```

But then I realized that I needed `clm` to be of size 50 (given that I do not know that `A` and `J` have a column `clm`).

Is there script/query in PG that can do this thing?

Comment: do you want increase the size of clm, in which tables are have that column? right

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'clm' to get all tables with col "clm"

Comment: @Sathish yes. Something like 'increase size where column_name = "clm"', which applies to tables A - Z.

Comment: @StefanSprenger This is a good start, I tried your query in MySQL and it works. I'll to work on the UPDATE operation.

Comment: @whoknows i am also looking for some kind of alter table iteration

Comment: @whoknows try this 
DO
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'clm'  
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE public.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) || 'ALTER COLUMN clm TYPE varchar(50);';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, single quotes for data. I fixed your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `text` or `varchar`, not `varchar(n)`. If you really need to restrict a column to a maximum length use a `CHECK` constraint. Related answer:

- [Change PostgreSQL columns used in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524873/change-postgresql-columns-used-in-views/8527792#8527792)

Anyway, the basic statement is:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER clm TYPE varchar(50); -- or rather: text
```

You don't need a `USING` clause with explicit conversion instructions, as long as there an implicit a cast registered, which is the case for `varchar(n)` -> `varchar(n)` / `text`. Details:

- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)

Script based on system catalogs:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    _sql text;
BEGIN
   FOR _sql IN 
      SELECT format('ALTER TABLE %s ALTER %I TYPE varchar(50)'
                   , attrelid::regclass
                   , a.attname)
      FROM   pg_namespace n
      JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
      JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
      WHERE  n.nspname = 'public'  -- your schema
      AND    a.attname = 'clm'     -- column name (case sensitive!)
      AND    a.attnum > 0
      AND    NOT a.attisdropped
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- debug before you execute
      -- EXECUTE _sql;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_sizeupdate()
 RETURNS Void AS
 $BODY$ 
 DECLARE 
 query text;

 BEGIN 

for query in 

select 'alter table '|| table_name ||' alter clm type varchar(50) 
USING clm ::varchar(50);'
from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public' and
column_name='name';

loop

execute query

 End loop;

END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: this is PostgreSQL syntax right? does this apply to INGRES. I can't test this coz' I don't have the environment. sorry.

Comment: @whoknows yes it `postgresql` syntax

Comment: @Sathish You can use `RETURNS void` instead of `RETURNS text` if you do not want to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not validated just "brain tested"

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'clm' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'public'  
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE public.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) || 'ALTER COLUMN clm TYPE varchar(50);';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: You need to include a `where table_schema = 'public'` into the select if you hardcode the schema in the `alter table` statement. And using `like` without a wildcard doesn't really make sense.