# Convert data type of column to timestamp using explicit cast

Tags: django, postgresql, types, timestamp, ddl

I'm running the following command to fix the error I've encountered with the Datefield() in my django model.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "end_date" cannot be cast 
automatically to type timestamp with time zone
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

Here is the line I'm running which doesn't seem to fix the problem:

```
ALTER TABLE merged_subscription ALTER COLUMN end_date TYPE timestamp USING to_timestamp(col, 'DD-MON-YYY');
```

I'm not very familiar with postresql. Is there something wrong with the logic here?

Here is my Django model for reference:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
issue_one = models.ForeignKey(Issue, blank=True, null=True, related_name='issue_one')
issue_two = models.ForeignKey(Issue, blank=True, null=True, related_name='issue_two')
issue_three = models.ForeignKey(Issue, blank=True, null=True, related_name='issue_three')
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.start_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE merged_subscription
 ALTER COLUMN end_date TYPE timestamp
 USING to_timestamp(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYY');
```

Replace the placeholder `col` with the actual column name.
Assuming that strings in `end_date` comply with the given (uncommon!) pattern. (?)

Are you sure you don't have `'DD-MON-YYYY'`?

If you actually have a [**`date`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) column, you don't need a `USING` clause. There is an *implicit* cast between `date` and `timestamp`, and an *assignment* cast is all that's required.

```
ALTER TABLE merged_subscription
 ALTER COLUMN end_date TYPE timestamp;
```

Details:

- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)