# array_agg group by and null

Tags: postgresql, null, group-by, left-join, generate-series

Given this table:

```
SELECT * FROM CommodityPricing order by dateField

"SILVER";60.45;"2002-01-01"
"GOLD";130.45;"2002-01-01"
"COPPER";96.45;"2002-01-01"
"SILVER";70.45;"2003-01-01"
"GOLD";140.45;"2003-01-01"
"COPPER";99.45;"2003-01-01"
"GOLD";150.45;"2004-01-01"
"MERCURY";60;"2004-01-01"
"SILVER";80.45;"2004-01-01"
```

As of 2004, COPPER was dropped and mercury introduced.
How can I get the value of `(array_agg(value order by date desc) ) [1]`  as `NULL` for `COPPER`?

```
select commodity,(array_agg(value order by date desc) ) --[1]
from CommodityPricing
group by commodity

"COPPER";"{99.45,96.45}"
"GOLD";"{150.45,140.45,130.45}"
"MERCURY";"{60}"
"SILVER";"{80.45,70.45,60.45}"
```

Comment: SQLFiddle for this sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f27f4

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/66fe5/1)

```
select
    commodity,
    array_agg(
        case when commodity = 'COPPER' then null else price end
        order by date desc
    )
from CommodityPricing
group by commodity
;
```

Answer (score 0):

To "pad" missing rows with null values in the resulting array, build your query on a **full grid of rows** and **`LEFT JOIN`** to actual values to the grid.

Given this table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE price (
  commodity text
, value     numeric
, ts        timestamp  -- using ts instead of the inappropriate name date 
);
```

Use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to get a list of timestamps representing the years and `CROSS JOIN` to a unique list of all commodities (`SELECT DISTINCT ...`).

```sql
SELECT commodity, array_agg(value ORDER BY ts DESC) AS years
FROM   generate_series (timestamp '2002-01-01'
                      , timestamp '2004-01-01'
                      , '1 year') t(ts)
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT commodity FROM price) c(commodity)
LEFT   JOIN price p USING (ts, commodity)
GROUP  BY commodity;
```

Result:

| commodity | years |
| --- | --- |
| COPPER | {NULL,99.45,96.45} |
| GOLD | {150.45,140.45,130.45} |
| MERCURY | {60,NULL,NULL} |
| SILVER | {80.45,70.45,60.45} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m_2cvmhs)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7696f/2)</sub>

Related:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)