# CARTO Animation Time Series Map

Tags: animation, gis, cartodb

Hello I am making a animation time series map in CARTO builder. The animation works fine, but I would like my points to continuously move from point A to B, not just populate from point A to B like its doing now if theres a vast distance for the particular ID for that point. I know this would work if I had many more coordinates filling in from point A to B like in this [example](http://www.storybench.org/use-cartodb-visualize-animal-tracking-data/), but I don't. So is there a way to do this in cartodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CARTO BUILDER allows you to analyze and visualize your data according to your values. So as you pointed out, you would need to enrich your dataset with data among those dates and locations. Regarding dates, you can use `generate_series` PostgreSQL function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql). In relation to generating points between two coordinates, you would need to create a line (via [`Connect with lines`](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/connect-with-lines) analysis or [`ST_MakeLine`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)) and then apply [`ST_DumpPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! That's all i needed to know:)