# How to display empty rows in this specific case?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, left-join, generate-series

I'm trying to build a query using the various examples I found here but with little success so far:

```
SELECT count(o.hist_create) AS daily_count, d.day AS date_column 
FROM  (
SELECT day::date FROM generate_series(
(SELECT hist_create FROM orders ORDER BY hist_create LIMIT 1),
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
interval '1 day')day)d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON date_trunc('day', o.hist_create) = d.day
WHERE o.customerId = '1234'
GROUP  BY d.day 
ORDER  BY d.day;
```

So here I want to count orders on a day to day basis from the first order's timestamp to today for a specific customer, and while this works, it doesn't fetch the dates when there was no order for this customer. I would like to see something like:

```
number | date 
     15| 06-12-2017 
     0 | 07-12-2017
     9 | 08-12-2017
     11| 09-12-2017
```

But I get:

```
number | date 
     15| 06-12-2017 
     9 | 08-12-2017
     11| 09-12-2017
```

I thought the join would take care of that and it seems this solution worked for others, maybe not when targeting a customer the way I do, though?

The data type of `hist_create` is `timestamp`.

Comment: I think you should show us some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're filtering on a field from the orders table, which defeats the purpose of using an outer join. Include that condition in your join instead:

```
SELECT count(o.hist_create) AS daily_count, d.day AS date_column 
FROM  (
SELECT day::date FROM generate_series(
(SELECT hist_create FROM orders ORDER BY hist_create LIMIT 1),
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
interval '1 day')day)d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON date_trunc('day', o.hist_create) = d.day AND o.customerId = '1234'

GROUP  BY d.day 
ORDER  BY d.day;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe I didn't see that, I'll wear a dunce cap for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 0):

@fauxmosapien pointed out your main issue with the `LEFT JOIN`.

But since your column `hist_create` has data type `timestamp`, the query can be further improved like this:

```
SELECT count(o.hist_create) AS daily_count, d.day::date AS date_column 
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(min(hist_create), now()::timestamp, interval '1 day') AS day
   FROM   orders
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN orders o ON date_trunc('day', o.hist_create) = d.day
                    AND o.customerId = '1234'  -- why is the number quoted?
GROUP  BY d.day 
ORDER  BY d.day;
```

Your original query generates a series of `timestamptz` values (because that's what [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) returns) casts to `date` before it has to cast back to `timestamp` for the match to `hist_create` in the `LEFT JOIN`.

Instead, create a `timestamp` series and match directly. Only cast to `date` for output (or format the value any way you like for display with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)). Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to verify that it performs slightly better. It also minimizes sneaky corner case errors with casting between timestamptz and date / timestamp. More details:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)