# How to get list day of month data per month in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i use psql v.10.5

and i have a structure table like this :

```
|     date      | total |
-------------------------
|  01-01-2018   |   50  |
|  05-01-2018   |   90  |
|  30-01-2018   |   20  |
```

how to get recap data by month, but the data showed straight 30 days, i want the data showed like this :

```
|     date      | total |
-------------------------
|  01-01-2018   |   50  |
|  02-01-2018   |   0   |
|  03-01-2018   |   0   |
|  04-01-2018   |   0   |
|  05-01-2018   |   90  |
.....
|  29-01-2018   |   0   |
|  30-01-2018   |   20  |
```

i've tried this query :

```
SELECT * FROM date
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM "date") = 1  // dynamically
AND EXTRACT(year FROM "date") = 2018  // dynamically
```

but the result is not what i expected. also the params of month and date i create dynamically.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: use `generate_series` example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function [`generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), e.g.:

```
select d::date, coalesce(total, 0) as total
from generate_series('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31', '1 day'::interval) d
left join my_table t on d::date = t.date
```

[Working example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/JOFZ79462)

Comment: To add to the above answer +1, this is an example of using a _calendar_ table, which contains all the dates you want to appear in your report, even if all dates don't appear in your actual data.