# Generate date series with repeating dates

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to generate a long date series that repeats each date 5 times, like below?

```
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
etc.
```

Comment: Does redshift have recursive  CTE's?

Comment: maybe there are other ways to solve your underlying challenge, if you update your question to explain WHY you need this table we may be able to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

**Redshift** is not Postgres. [Does not support `generate_series()`.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

The poor man's default is a **number table** (starting with 1). Create it once per database. [Like demonstrated here.](http://elliot.land/post/redshift-does-not-support-generate-series)

Then:

```
SELECT date '2018-1-1' + day.number - 1
FROM   number AS day
     , number AS repeat
WHERE  day.number    <= 10  -- number of days in date range
AND    repeat.number <= 5   -- number of repetitions
ORDER  BY day.number;
```

---

In **Postgres**, you can use `generate_series()` directly:

```
SELECT day::date
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2018-1-1'  -- desired date range
                     , timestamp '2018-1-5'  -- preferably in ISO foramt
                     , interval '1 day') day
     , generate_series(1,5) repeat;          -- number of repetitions
```

That's a `CROSS JOIN`, generating a Carthesian product, so each date is repeated 5 times in the example. Output is type is `date` after the cast. Why `timestamp` arguments? See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

To get your particular date format use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE):

```
SELECT to_char(day, 'FMMM/FMDD/YYYY')
FROM   ...
```

This is ordered like your example by default, but that's an implementation detail. If you need to guarantee a particular order, add `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks Erwin.  It's showing a days.num does not exist error.  Do numbers in the numbers table need to be consecutive?

Comment: Yes, need to be consecutive. `days.num`? That's from an earlier version, right? Did you try the latest version? (Using `day.number` now.)