# SQL generate_series and use it for join

Tags: sql, date, join, amazon-redshift, sequence

I am trying to generate a list of dates on Redshift to join it with another table with a start and end date of events so that I can have a list of event ids for each date.

This query produces the list of dates:

```
select date '2023-03-01' + i AS dt
from  generate_series(0, ((current_date - 5) - date '2023-03-01')) i)
```

| dt |
| --- |
| 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-03-02 |
| 2023-03-03 |
| ... |

This looks into the events table:

```
select e_id, start_date, end_date
from  tableA
```

| e_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-04 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-05 |
| 3 | 2023-03-02 | 2023-03-03 |

I have tried this query:

```
with dl as (
select date '2023-03-01' + i AS dt
from  generate_series(0, ((current_date - 5) - date '2023-03-01')) i)
)
, e as (
select e_id, start_date, end_date
from  tableA
)
select dt, e_id
from dl
left join e on dl.dt >= e.start_date and dl.dt <= e.end_date
```

but I get the following error:

```
NOTICE: Function "generate_series(integer,integer)" not supported.
Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

Given the examples above, I would expect the following result:

| dt | e_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 | 1 |
| 2023-03-02 | 1 |
| 2023-03-02 | 3 |
| 2023-03-03 | 1 |
| 2023-03-03 | 2 |
| 2023-03-03 | 3 |
| 2023-03-04 | 1 |
| 2023-03-04 | 2 |
| 2023-03-05 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

generate_series() is not supported as a means to make data for use against your table data. There are many answers to why (hardware architecture) and using a recursive CTE to generate the same results.  One such recursive CTE to generate date from a previous answer:

[trying to create a date table in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883072/trying-to-create-a-date-table-in-redshift/69901710#69901710)

==========================================================

Again from a previous answer (but much older): You can generate an arbitrary sequence of number using binary power approach and cross-joining.  See:

[Redshift: Generate a sequential range of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491424/redshift-generate-a-sequential-range-of-numbers/66497715#66497715)

Once the sequence of necessary numbers are created you use this to add days to a starting date up until your necessary end date.

Comment: Thank you @bill-weiner ! This works for getting the desired output. However, unfortunately I cannot use recursive CTEs because I have to enter the query into a third party server that does not support recursive CTEs for Redshift connections. Is there really no way of producing a list of dates in Redshift without a recursive CTE?

Comment: Recursive CTEs are fairly new in Redshift so yes, there are older methods for doing this.  I'm assuming you need a query that will work in both databases so I'll pick one that should do this.  I'll update my answer with a binary math method that should meet the need.