# Fill missing dates in PostgreSQL with zero

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I've a query like this in PostgreSQL:

```
select count(id_student) students, date_beginning_course from 
data.sessions_courses
left join my_schema.students on id_session_course=id_sesion 
where course_name='First course'
group by date_beginning_course
```

What I obtain with this query is the number of students that have attended a session of "First course" in several dates, for example:

```
Students  Date_beginning_course
____________________________________

5         2019-06-26
1         2019-06-28
5         2019-06-30
6         2019-07-01
2         2019-07-02
```

I'd like to fill this table with the missing date values, and, for each missing value, assign a '0' in Students column, because there are no students for this date. Example:

```
Students  Date_beginning_course
____________________________________

5         2019-06-26
0         2019-06-27  <--new row
1         2019-06-28
0         2019-06-29  <--new row
5         2019-06-30
6         2019-07-01
2         2019-07-02
```

Could you help me? Thanks! :)

Comment: Use a `calendar table` (probably `generate-series()`) and left join to that.

Comment: Indeed. Join to a subquery that uses `generate_series()` to create a range of dates, as per @wildplassers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113580/256196)

Comment: I've tried to use a generate_series query with no success, I think I'm not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could generate a list of dates with the handy [Postgres set-returning function `generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) and `LEFT JOIN` it with the `sessions_courses` and `students` table:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(s.id_student) students, 
    d.dt
FROM 
    (
        SELECT dt::date 
        FROM generate_series('2019-06-26', '2019-07-02', '1 day'::interval) dt
    ) d
    LEFT JOIN data.sessions_courses c 
        ON c.date_beginning_course  = d.dt 
        AND c.course_name='First course'
    LEFT JOIN my_schema.students s 
        ON s.id_session_course = c.id_session 
GROUP BY d.dt
```

You can change the date range by modifying the first two parameters of `generate_series()`.

NB: it is a general good practive to index the column names in the query with the relevant table names (or table alias), so it is explicit to which table each column belongs. I changed your query accordingly, and had to make a few assumptions, that you might need to adapt.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not working well, because when I add more filters in WHERE clause my table returns all the results, not filtered :(

Comment: @belfastcowboy24: not sure what you mean... Anyway there was a mistake in the query: I just removed the `WHERE` clause; all filtering criterias should be placed in the `ON` clause of the relevant `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @belfastcowboy24 . . . This appears to answer the question that you asked.  You should accept this question.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.