# Basic left join is not working on PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables which I want to left join. One with dates ranging between 2 Augustus 2023 - 10 augustus 2023. I want to join this with my ad interaction table. The Ad interaction table only has interactions from 8,9 and 10 August. I wanted the final table to show the number of ad interactions for each date, if there are none it should show 0. However, my code now just skips the date and does not show 0. I don't understand why, since I am doing a LEFT JOIN.

I used [this link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-joins/) to check if the join is correct.

```
select dt::date, ads.interaction.created_at::date as ad_interaction_date, count(*) as interactions 
from 
    generate_series('2023-08-02', '2023-08-10', '1 day'::interval) as dt
    left join ads.interaction 
    on dt::date = ads.interaction.created_at::date
where ad_id = 'bdc9dd4d-3d50-4813-89c1-08939eca5709'
group by dt::date, ads.interaction.created_at::date
```

[image]

So, to clarify, the table now is not showing rows with 'dt' = 2023-08-02 up to 2023-08-07. I used the `generate_series` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898023/fill-missing-dates-in-postgresql-with-zero) question.

Comment: `where ad_id = 'bdc9dd4d-3d50-4813-89c1-08939eca5709'` is filtering out the rows where `ads` is `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT dt::date, ads.interaction.created_at::date as ad_interaction_date, 
count(ads.interaction.created_at) as interactions 
FROM generate_series('2023-08-02', '2023-08-10', '1 day'::interval) as dt
LEFT JOIN ads.interaction 
ON dt::date = ads.interaction.created_at::date AND ads.interaction.ad_id = 
'bdc9dd4d-3d50-4813-89c1-08939eca5709'
GROUP BY dt::date, ads.interaction.created_at::date
 ORDER BY dt::date;
```