# Use the result of CASE expression in window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, date-arithmetic

The following SQL script generates 2022 year calendar with months, quarters, half-years and days count for each calendar interval:

```
with clndr as
(
select
    gs_day::date
from
    generate_series('2022-01-01'::timestamp, current_timestamp, '1 day') as gs_day
),
draft as
(
select 
     gs_day::date as gs_day
    ,count(*) over() as full_year_days_cnt
    ,date_trunc( 'month', gs_day)::date as mnth
    ,count(*) over(partition by to_char(gs_day::date , 'MM')) as full_month_days_cnt
    ,case
        when to_char(gs_day::date , 'MM') in ('01', '02', '03') then 1
        when to_char(gs_day::date , 'MM') in ('04', '05', '06') then 2
        when to_char(gs_day::date , 'MM') in ('07', '08', '09') then 3
        when to_char(gs_day::date , 'MM') in ('10', '11', '12') then 4
     end as year_quarter
    ,case 
        when to_char(gs_day::date, 'MM') in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06') then 1
        when to_char(gs_day::date, 'MM') in ('07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12') then 2
        else null
     end as year_half
from
    generate_series('2022-01-01'::timestamp, current_timestamp, '1 day') as gs_day
)

select
     gs_day
    ,full_year_days_cnt
    ,mnth
    ,full_month_days_cnt
    ,year_quarter
    ,count(*) over(partition by year_quarter) as year_quarter_days_cnt
    ,year_half
    ,count(*) over(partition by year_half) as year_half_days_cnt
from
    draft
```

Unfortunately, I have to use cte "draft" to count "year_quarter_days_cnt" and "year_half_days_cnt", because I didn't find any way to refer to "year_quarter" and "year_half" aliases in select statement of draft cte.

Is there any possibilities to avoid cte or joins to get the same result using count window function?

Comment: well... try it and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to a column alias ("output" column name) in the same `SELECT` list, only to input column names. So you would repeat (spell out again) a `CASE` statement in a window function to avoid a subquery or CTE.

Luckily, you don't seem to need these convoluted `CASE` expressions to begin with ...

```sql
SELECT d::date AS the_day
     , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY extract('year' FROM d)) AS full_year_days_cnt
     , date_trunc('month', d)::date AS month
     , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', d)) AS full_month_days_cnt
     , extract('quarter' FROM d)::int AS year_quarter
     , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY extract('year' FROM d), extract('quarter' FROM d)) AS year_quarter_days_cnt
     ,(extract('quarter' FROM d)::int + 1) / 2 AS year_half
     , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY extract('year' FROM d), (extract('quarter' FROM d)::int + 1) / 2) AS year_half_days_cnt
FROM   generate_series('2022-01-01'::timestamp, LOCALTIMESTAMP, '1 day') d
```

This also works for *any* given start date, optionally spanning multiple years - as opposed to your original.

Your leading CTE `clndr` was dead freight.
The CTE `draft` can be optimized away, as requested.
I also simplified and/or improved the rest.

Instead of `(PARTITION BY extract('year' FROM d), extract('quarter' FROM d)` you might also use `(PARTITION BY to_char(d, 'YYYY-Q'))`. But there is no equivalent simplification for `year_half_days_cnt`.

I also replaced `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with `LOCALTIMESTAMP` to avoid involving `timestamptz` a priori. Cleaner, faster. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)