# SQL to omit initial records until a column value is greater than zero

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table in Postgres named `personal_profit` as shown below:

| date | profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-22 | 4000 |
| 2022-04-25 | 5000 |
| 2022-01-10 | 0 |
| 2022-02-14 | 0 |
| 2022-04-12 | 2000 |
| 2022-05-06 | 1000 |
| 2022-06-13 | 0 |

I want to get total profit ordered by month but starting with the month having profit greater than zero. The query below omits all the records with zero profit which doesn't satisfy my condition. I just want the query to start from the month 04/2022.

```
Select distinct date_trunc('month', P.date) as profit_month, SUM(P.profit) as total_profit
from personal_profit P
group by profit_month
having SUM(P.profit) > 0
order by profit_month;
```

| date | profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04 | 7000 |
| 2022-05 | 1000 |
| 2022-06 | 0 |
| 2022-09 | 4000 |

Comment: No need to SELECT DISTINCT, your GROUP BY has already eliminated the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to start where, ordered by date, there is a non-zero value you can simply add that as a *where* criteria:

```
Select date_trunc('month', P.date) as profit_month, SUM(P.profit) as total_profit
from personal_profit  p
where date >= (select date from personal_profit where profit >0 order by date limit 1 )
group by profit_month
order by profit_month;
```

[demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jNn78sGP)

Comment: Well, this is the simplest approach, IMHO. Not adding unnecessary queries after `group by`. I believe you can remove the `distinct` since we have a `group by`.

Comment: Yes of course - I did actually but copied the OP's original statement and accidentally left it in; have removed.

Comment: I was thinking of a far more complex solution, when something as simple as this does the trick perfectly.

Comment: Should perform excellently even on a big table with an index on `(date, profit)`.  Let me just suggest to use `date_trunc('month', p.date::timestamp)` instead. Else, the `date` is coerced to `timestamptz` and that drags in the time zone setting of the current session. Nothing breaks in this simple query, but it adds a bit of cost and complication for no benefit at all. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860

Answer (score 1):

The condition "starting with the month having profit greater than zero" essentially means "skip the longest subsequence of zeros from the beginning". This can be achieved via selecting months with nonzero running total or via subquery. I consider the first way more comprehensible:

```
with personal_profit (date,profit) as (values
  (date '2022-09-22', 4000),
  (date '2022-04-25', 5000),
  (date '2022-01-10', 0),
  (date '2022-02-14', 0),
  (date '2022-04-12', 2000),
  (date '2022-05-06', 1000),
  (date '2022-06-13', 0)
)
, grouped as (
  select date_trunc('month', P.date) as profit_month
       , sum(P.profit) as total_profit
       , sum(sum(P.profit)) over (order by date_trunc('month', P.date)) as running_total
  from personal_profit P
  group by profit_month
)
select profit_month, total_profit
from grouped
where running_total > 0
order by profit_month;
```

| profit_month | total_profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 00:00:00+01 | 7000 |
| 2022-05-01 00:00:00+01 | 1000 |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00+01 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00+01 | 4000 |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/twVcCX1S)

Note the `running_total` expression should read `sum(total_profit) over (order by profit_month)` in ideal world, however Postgres is not aware of aliases in same `select` clause (even the `group by <alias_from_select_clause>` is Postgres' sugar and is unusual for other db vendors).

Answer (score 0):

you can check the month where you got first over 0 and use that to filter all values

```
Select to_char(P."date", 'YYYY-MM') as profit_month, SUM(P.profit) as total_profit
from personal_profit P

group by profit_month
having to_char(P."date", 'YYYY-MM') >= (Select  
 DISTINCT  MIN(
  to_char(P."date", 'YYYY-MM')
  ) over() as min_month
from personal_profit P
GROUP BY to_char(P."date", 'YYYY-MM')
having SUM(P.profit) > 0
)
order by profit_month;
```

| profit_month | total_profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04 | 7000 |
| 2022-05 | 1000 |
| 2022-06 | 0 |
| 2022-09 | 4000 |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pPh4xTAA)