# SQL query to group table by hourly buckets with missing values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table `orders` with a column `order_date` which is the timestamp of the order. For ML type analysis I want to group them into hourly buckets. Unfortunately if a given hour does not have any orders ex: 1PM this would not show up in the results. I'd like result to be like

```
2024-02-07-09-00 25
2024-02-07-10-00 37
2024-02-07-11-00 12
2024-02-07-12-00 20
2024-02-07-13-00 0 
2024-02-07-14-00 25
```

My current query

```
SELECT
    TO_TIMESTAMP(order_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00') AS mydate,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    orders
GROUP BY
    mydate
ORDER BY
    mydate
```

Obviously I can create a temporary table with all the 1 hour increments and then do a join but this sounded so basic (plus I don't have privileges to create temporary tables) that there may be something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned you will need some source with all the hours populated.  However you don't need a table for this you can generate this on the fly with a recursive cte.

Here's a previous answer where someone wanted the minutes of the day - [Date hour minute table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008548/date-hour-minute-table/76009198#76009198)

Here's an untested version of that code updated for your case:

```
with recursive cte(hr) as
(
  select '2024-02-07 00:00:00'::timestamp as hr
  union all
  select hr + interval '1 hour'
  from cte
  where cte.hr < '2024-02-07 23:00:00'::timestamp
)
select * from cte
```

You can JOIN this to your data like you say or UNION and sum().  Depending on your case second option may be faster.

Comment: This is an excellent idea! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that every hour is accounted for, we need to create a list of all the hourly timestamps we're interested in, regardless of whether there are orders during those hours. Since you don't have the privilege to create temporary tables, we can use a method called a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate this list dynamically.

We start by defining the starting timestamp, in this case '2024-02-07 09:00:00'. Then, we recursively add 1 hour to this timestamp until we reach our desired end time, '2024-02-07 14:00:00'. This process creates a list of hourly timestamps.

Once we have this list, we can perform a left join with your orders table. This join ensures that every timestamp in our list is matched with any orders that occurred during that hour. If there are no orders for a particular hour, the join still includes that hour in the result set, but the order count for that hour will be zero.

By using this approach, we ensure that all hourly increments are accounted for, even if there are no orders during certain hours.

Comment: This is more well suited for a comment. It doesn't give OP anything demonstrable or reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it gets much better than a generated sequence. Seen very clever stuff done in SQL Server with cross apply though.

Rationale: Implements what you've already described, with a CTE rather than temp table. Written for Postgres 16, but Redshift is based off Postgres so it ought to be portable.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/SNh25OKc

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_date TIMESTAMP(3)
);

INSERT INTO orders (order_date)
VALUES
('2024-02-27 09:23:15.123'),
('2024-02-27 10:45:32.456'),
('2024-02-27 10:34:21.789'),
('2024-02-27 13:58:49.321'),
('2024-02-27 15:26:18.654'),
('2024-02-27 17:37:56.987'),
('2024-02-27 19:40:27.234'),
('2024-02-27 19:59:34.567'),
('2024-02-27 19:15:42.890'),
('2024-02-27 23:48:10.123'),
('2024-02-27 02:36:28.456'),
('2024-02-27 04:17:49.789'),
('2024-02-27 05:53:14.321'),
('2024-02-27 07:25:58.654'),
('2024-02-27 01:28:36.987'),
('2024-02-27 03:11:27.234'),
('2024-02-27 06:42:58.567'),
('2024-02-27 06:30:49.890'),
('2024-02-27 11:02:12.123'),
('2024-02-27 14:23:35.456'),
('2024-02-27 16:57:18.789'),
('2024-02-27 18:39:45.321'),
('2024-02-27 21:10:28.654'),
('2024-02-27 23:55:16.987');

with hours_in_range as 
  (
    select bucket
      from
    generate_series
            ( (select min(date_trunc('hour', order_date)) from orders)::timestamp 
            , (select max(date_trunc('hour', order_date)) from orders)::timestamp 
            , '1 hour'::interval) bucket
  )
select hr.bucket,
       count(o.order_date) as orders_in_hour
  from hours_in_range hr
  left
  join orders o
    on hr.bucket = date_trunc('hour', o.order_date)
 group
    by hr.bucket;

| bucket | orders\_in\_hour |
|:-------|---------------:|
| 2024-02-27 01:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 02:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 03:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 04:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 05:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 06:00:00 | 2 |
| 2024-02-27 07:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 2024-02-27 09:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 10:00:00 | 2 |
| 2024-02-27 11:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 12:00:00 | 0 |
| 2024-02-27 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 14:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 16:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 17:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 18:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 19:00:00 | 3 |
| 2024-02-27 20:00:00 | 0 |
| 2024-02-27 21:00:00 | 1 |
| 2024-02-27 22:00:00 | 0 |
| 2024-02-27 23:00:00 | 2 |
```

Comment: Unfortunately generate_series() is a leader only function on Redshift and cannot be used with user data.  I'm guessing this code / result was generated on a different db.

Comment: @BillWeiner Ah, good catch. Mentioned in the answer it was written for Postgres, thought Postgres and Redshift shared pretty much the same dialect. Guess not completely https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html . Good to know.