# Generate daily rate from a monthly generated series

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table called `budgets` containing a `rate` and a `time_span` I want to generate a monthly daily rate for each day. The `time_span` must have a start date but can be open ended `["2023-06-02 00:00:00+00",)`.

For example given the following dataset:

- `rate`: $10
- `time_span`: `["2023-07-19 00:00:00+00",)`

Assume the current day is `2023-09-05 00:00:00+00` I would expect the query result to show:

- `2023-07-19 -> 2023-08-18` a `rate` of `$10` should be divided 30 way for a daily rate of `$0.333`
- `2023-08-19 -> 2023-09-05` a `rate` of `$10` should be divided 17 days for a daily rate of `$0.588`

**Attempt 1:**

I have first attempted to solve this by generating a series from the `time_span` then dividing the rate against the `date_part` interval of one month. This is flawed as the `time_bucket` in the `date_part` does not account for the correct number of days within its monthly window.

```
SELECT
   CAST(time_bucket AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS time_bucket,
   rate / DATE_PART('days', time_bucket + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day') AS daily_rate
FROM (
   SELECT
      DATE(generate_series(LOWER(time_span)::TIMESTAMP, COALESCE(UPPER(time_span),NOW())::TIMESTAMP, '1 day')) AS time_bucket,
      rate
   FROM budgets
) AS daily_rates;
```

How do I generate the daily rate on a monthly basis for this budgets table?

- `2023-07-19` - `0.333`
- `2023-07-20` - `0.333`
- `2023-07-21` - `0.333`
- ....
- `2023-08-19` - `0.588`
- `2023-08-20` - `0.588`
- ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT mon_start::date + i AS the_day, round(rate/mon_days, 3) AS daily_rate
FROM   budgets b
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *,  LEAST(mon_start + interval '1 month', '2023-09-05')::date - mon_start::date AS mon_days
   FROM   generate_series (lower(timespan)::timestamp
                         , LEAST(upper(timespan)::timestamp, '2023-09-05')
                         , interval '1 month') mon_start
   ) m
     , generate_series (0, m.mon_days - 1) i
WHERE  id = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gSKi2HUC)

Note the rate for the first month of your example is **0.323** not <strike>0.333</strike>, since August has 31 days, not 30.

1. Generates a series of months in the first lateral subquery `m`
   Calculate the number of day in this rate period of a month or shorter: `mon_days`
2. Generate as many rows as there are days in `mon_days` in the second lateral function call `i` - effectively just shorthand for `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`. See:

   - [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
3. Compute the display date `the_day` and its `daily_rate` in the outer `SELECT`.

There is a lot of fine print to this kind of calculation:

To avoid undefined corner cases and ambiguities with time zones vs. local time and daylight saving time, I build on the data type [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) for `time_span` instead of [`tstzrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) like your sample data suggests.

Like your sample data suggests, I base monthly slices off the actual start date in `timespan`, not the first of the month.

I assume you want to end the time series with the current date, so I use `LEAST` instead of `COALESCE`. (And another `LEAST` for a different reason.)

I divide the rate by the actual number of days in each monthly slice.

`rate` should be type numeric to avoid rounding errors and work with `round()` out of the box.

I assume all columns `NOT NULL`.

Note that [`date - date → int`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) and [`date + int → date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE).

I base the first `generate_series()` call on `timestamp`, not `date`, because:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Your actual query will use the actual current date (or timestamp) instead of the given, fixed 2023-09-05 for "today":

```sql
SELECT mon_start::date + i AS the_day, round(rate/mon_days, 3) AS daily_rate, *
FROM   budgets b
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *,  LEAST(mon_start + interval '1 month', LOCALTIMESTAMP)::date - mon_start::date AS mon_days
   FROM   generate_series (lower(timespan)::timestamp
                         , LEAST(upper(timespan)::timestamp, LOCALTIMESTAMP)  -- !
                         , interval '1 month') mon_start
   ) m
     , generate_series (0, m.mon_days - 1) i
WHERE  id = $id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't adhere exactly to your structure for simplicity and it wasn't clear exactly how you wanted the output presented. But I threw together a SQL Fiddle to show the basic structure of a possible solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d52a4/14

The essential bit

```
with a as (
  select generate_series(start_ts, coalesce(end_ts, now()), '1 day') dt
       , start_ts
       , end_ts
       , rate 
    from budgets
)
, b as (
  select rate
       , start_ts
       , end_ts
       , dt
       , date_part('month',age(dt, start_ts::date)) 
         + (date_part('year',age(dt, start_ts::date)) * 12) as mon 
  from a
)
select min(dt)
     , max(dt)
     , round(rate / count(dt), 2)
  from b 
 group by mon, rate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(rate, timespan, n) as (
   select b.rate, b.timespan, least(b.timespan + interval '30 day', now())::timestamp 
   from budgets b
   union all
   select c.rate, c.n + interval '1 day', least(c.n + interval '30 day', now())::timestamp 
   from cte c where c.n < now()
) 
select t, c.rate / extract(days from c.n - c.timespan) from cte c 
cross join generate_series(c.timespan, c.n, interval '1 day') t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HZX2FutO)