# How can I create state timeline graph with Grafana?

Tags: grafana, pgadmin

Could you give me a hint on how to create the graph with Grafana?
I would like to show the merging time of the Github PR. and got data from PgAdmin like this:

```
    | number | created_at | merged_at | closed_at |
    |--------|------------|-----------|-----------|
    | int    | timestamp  | timestamp | timestamp |
```

I want to display like this:

```
x axis - timeseries
y axis - number
```

```
if merged_at = null then merged_at = 9999-12-31:23:59:59
```

Status:

```
when created_at < time < merged_at -> OPEN
else when time > closed_at -> CLOSE
else when time > merged_at -> MERGED
```

e.g.

```
|
|
|
| 230              +++++OPEN++++++++|----------MERGED---------------------
| 231                      ++++++++OPEN+++++++++|**********CLOSED*********
```

what kind of table do I need for this graph?

Comment: You'll need to generate sequence of timestamps between `$__to` and `$__from` with specified step, and then for every timestamp get PRs state. I believe it can be done with [`generate_series`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113580/21363224).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved this problem with the partition on the transportation tab in Grafana.