# How to add new timestamp column and populate it times incrementing by 1 second

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has about 60 million rows that I use for testing. I want to add a column `test_time` that should be unique across all rows and spaced 1 second apart from each other.

So for instance:

```
Row 1: 2024-01-01 00:00:00
Row 2: 2024-01-01 00:00:01
Row 3: 2024-01-01 00:00:02
Row 4: 2024-01-01 00:00:03
...
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this through SQL or do I need to write a script to connect to the db and manually do this?

Comment: You can do it through SQL, using `DATEADD(ss,numOfSeconds,DateField)`

Comment: See also [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113580/1255289)

Answer (score 3):

You can use generate sequence function,

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2024-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,
                              '2024-01-01 12:00:00', '1 second');
```

[image]

For your requirement, use row_number with your actual table and join it with the above query and generate the date with second difference

Comment: I don't even use Postgres and it took me all of 30 seconds to find multiple duplicates for this question. Please avoid answering questions that have already been answered elsewhere.